# How do I get more than 250 calendar items using the .net client library?

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to use the .net client library for Google Calendar. I can get a list of Calendars and get a list of events on a Calendar. However, I get a maximum of 250 items per Calendar. How do I access the rest? I'm aware of the 'pagetoken' in Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.EventsResource.ListRequest, however in the code example below, itemlistreq.PageToken remains null, even for a calendar with more than 250 items.

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);

var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
initializer.Authenticator = auth;

var calsrv = new CalendarService(initializer);

//Get list of calendars
var list = calsrv.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items;

//Get entry list for each calendar
foreach(var cal in list)
{
    var itemlistreq = calsrv.Events.List(cal.Id);
    var itemlistex = itemlistreq.Execute();
    var itemlist = itemlistex.Items;

    //Here, itemlistreq.PageToken == null, even if itemlist has 250 entries.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to change the MaxResult property on the request?
For example, try doing the following:

```
var itemlistreq = calsrv.Events.List(cal.Id);
itemlistreq.MaxResults = 10000;
var itemlistex = itemlistreq.Execute();
var itemlist = itemlistex.Items;
```

UPDATED:
Try getting the NextPageToekn property from the Events class (itemlistex in your case)

```
var itemlistreq = calsrv.Events.List(cal.Id);
var itemlistex = itemlistreq.Execute();
var token = itemlistex.NextPageToken; // THAT IS THE TOKEN YOU ARE LOOKING FOR
var itemlist = itemlistex.Items;
```

Then you can set it on the itemlistex.PageToken property to get more events...

Comment: Yes, I did that already. If MaxResults is >250, the amount of results stays 250, if it's <250, the amount of results is indeed limited to what you pass as MaxResults. And no effect on PageToken, that stays null in both cases.

Comment: I've updated the answer, and add the itemlistex.NextPageToken call. Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

the MaxResult is limited to 2500 items, so 10000 will not work

Comment: Could you provide a link for reference to confirm this?

Comment: You can find the API in here [Google Developer] (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) the relevant method is maxResults, and as you can see it's limited to 2500

Comment: If you want to receive more than that, you can iterate the pages, which is the best way to handle it anyway.